# linux create new private key from existing public key

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

Let's say you set up a public/private key pair to log in to a linux server. Now you want another computer to be able to log into that same linux server. How in linux could you generate a new private key from that public key?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: The whole point of public-key encryption is not being able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot generate a private key from a public key.  Instead you create a public/private pair of keys on your new computer and send the public key to your server.  That way messages encrypted by your new computer can be decrypted by your server.